# JavaScript alert with 3 buttons

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript alert button that appears on the website when a user is going to proceed to a signup page.

It looks something like this

Would you like to proceed to the signup page?
< OK > < Cancel >

Would it be possible to add a third button to the alert so that it looks like

Would you like to proceed to the signup page?
< More Info > < OK > < Cancel >

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No.

You need to use a custom modal dialog, such as [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Answer (score 6):

Nowdays, you can use an HTML `dialog` element.

```
<dialog open>
  <p>Greetings, one and all!</p>
  <button>Ok</button><button>Maybe</button><button>Cancel</button>
</dialog>
```

And do what you want with it.

```
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach($button => 
  $button.onclick = () => document.querySelector('dialog').removeAttribute('open'))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6nus2zt4/1/

Hope this helps to future generations :)

Answer (score 4):

however you can use confirm function.. but NOT three buttons.

```
var r=confirm("Press a button!");
if (r==true)
  {
  x="You pressed OK!";
  }
 else
  {
  x="You pressed Cancel!";
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can change the number of buttons in an alert box.  (At least not in any browser that I know of.)  You can use one of the many modal dialog scripts that are out on the net.  Something like Eric Martin's [SimpleModal Dialog](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) for jquery would probably work.

They basically take a div and style it up with css and javascript to mimic a dialog box.