# Alert with multiple options

Tags: javascript, alert

Just wondering, is it possible to create an alert with multiple options?

Like for example, in Facebook, when you try to close the tab/window when you have not finished typing your message, an alert with the options "Leave this page" and "Stay on this page" will pop up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript alert with 3 buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054082/javascript-alert-with-3-buttons)

Comment: @Andy But you can't name `confirm()` options.

Comment: @Andy Then how did the creator of the Facebook site do it? How did he give the alert two options that have names besides "Ok" and "Cancel"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example with form, you'are looking for window.onbeforeunload:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var originalFormContent
var checkForChanges = true;

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    originalFormContent = jQuery('#myForm input[type=text]').serialize() +      jQuery('#myForm select').serialize();
});

function onClose() {

    if (checkForChanges && originalFormContent != "undefined") {
        var content = jQuery('#myForm input[type=text]').serialize() + jQuery('#myForm select').serialize();
        if (content != originalFormContent) {

            return confirm('You have unsaved changes.  Click OK if you wish to continue ,click Cancel to return to your form.');
        }
    }

}

window.onbeforeunload = onClose();
```

Answer (score 4):

You're referring to `window.onbeforeunload`:

[Best way to detect when a user leaves a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-a-user-leaves-a-web-page)

You can also use the `window.confirm()` function for `OK`/`Cancel` options:

http://jsfiddle.net/UFw4k/1

Other than that, you'd have to implement a custom modal alert, such as [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default

Copied this from a previous answer: [JavaScript alert with 3 buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054082/javascript-alert-with-3-buttons)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.