# Popup window with three buttons

Tags: javascript, html, web

I need to popup a window with three buttons when the user clicks on a text.

What I have in my java class:

```
myHtml.append("<a href=\"" + myUrl+ "\" onclick=\"javascript: return confirm('" + myMessage + "')\">" + myLink + "</a>");
```

What I need is to not use "confirm". I need to use a popup similar to `confirm()` but with 3 different actions.

How can I replace `confirm()` to have 3 different actions instead of "ok" and "cancel" only?

**EDIT**

I have another idea, I can call prompt from the java class but my problem is how to get the prompt result inside my java class??

```
myHtml.append("<a href=\"" + myUrl + "\" onclick=\"javascript: return prompt('" + myMessage + "')\">" + myLink + "</a>");
```

Comment: Use jquery ui dialog or some other custom plugins.

Comment: Why is this tagged with “java”?  JavaScript and Java are completely different things.

Comment: @VGR Because Struts is Java, I assume, and the framework may include relevant functionality. (As it doesn't differentiate between Struts 1 and Struts 2, however, it's hard to say.)

Comment: I can't add jquery to my project, im not using it at all. Please can you help me after I edited my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript alert with 3 buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054082/javascript-alert-with-3-buttons)

Comment: What are you doing is just rendering escaped html with a javascript, Struts in reality using some templates do do it in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think an alert pop-up with three buttons would be possible without using JQuery or some other custom dialog box. (As already pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054082/javascript-alert-with-3-buttons))

Since you're calling the `prompt()` function as part of your html document, I don't see a possibility to return the result to your java program as well. You could, however, expand your function attached to the `onclick` attribute in order to send it to your java program, even if I don't think this would be an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an script for that customized pop-up window with three buttons. Try this once.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:100,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Button 1": function() {
          $(this).dialog( "<something>");
        },
        "Button 2": function() {
          $(this).dialog( "<something>");
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $(this).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
```

In the body tag of your html page. use following :

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Your text here.</p>
</div>
```